# Html5 canvas element pixel grid ( pageX and pageY)

Tags: html, angular, canvas, html5-canvas

Hey I'm trying to make a drawing app using html canvas and I'll trace the coordinates of canvas using mouse events and everything went fine.  I set my canvas to `scr.width` and `scr.height` to make it full screen board..
I'll store all the mouse events in an array for making drawing  on canvas
Now the problem is,
Say suppose I used `1920*1080` resolution screen, as mentioned above my canvas will be `1920*1080` (full screen)
And I started storing all my mouse events and pushed it to back-end.
Now I opened my site in 1440 resolution. I cannot see few drawing.
Reason: in `1920*1080` , I traced points above 1440 and stored it in back-end.
When I get it back , from back-end to front in different resolution, I cannot draw all the points which are above 1440 because my screen size max is 1440.

Can anyone tell me a solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Framework used: angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to introduce a scale factor.
You should store the original height and width of the canvas when you save it i.e. 1920 x 1080.

For new drawings.

```
let scale = 1;
```

For existing drawings calculate a scale factor. This assumes the new screen resolution is proportional to the old.

```
let scale = currentWidth / originalWidth;  // 1440 / 1920 = 0.75
```

Now use the scale factor for all drawing. e.g.

```
context.arc(x * scale, y * scale, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
```